# Dart - Convert time from dd/MM/YYYY to YYYY-MM-dd

Tags: datetime, flutter, dart

How to convert a date from `dd/MM/YYYY` to `YYYY-MM-dd`

Example: convert from `08/11/2019` to `2019-11-08`

I tried the following code but got the

> Invalid date format `08/11/2019` exception

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

DateFormat('YYYY-MM-dd').format(DateTime.parse('08.11.2019'));
```

Comment: It should be `yyyy` not `YYYY`.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
var inputFormat = DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');
var date1 = inputFormat.parse('18/08/2019');

var outputFormat = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
var date2 = outputFormat.format(date1); // 2019-08-18
```

Or you can use `String`

```
var date2String = outputFormat.format(date1); // "2019-08-18"
```

Comment: how about from 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss' to 'HH:mm:ss'? @CopsOnRoad

Comment: Thanks to @dumzy for better names.

Comment: @BismaFrühling You can do pretty much anything with the above code, make sure you don't make mistakes in case sensitive words.

Comment: Check out the updated code, it is working as expected.

Comment: To convert `dd-MM-yyyy` to `yyyy-MM-dd` use this `DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').parse(value))`

Answer (score 1):

Try using this package, [Jiffy](https://pub.dev/packages/jiffy). It is inspired by [momentjs](https://momentjs.com).

This can be solved in one line

```
var dateTime = Jiffy("18/08/2019", "dd/MM/yyyy").format("yyyy-MM-dd"); // 2019-08-18
```

You can also format it with default formats

```
var dateTime = Jiffy("18/08/2019", "dd/MM/yyyy").yMMMMd; // August 18, 2019
```