# How to return only the records from the last 24hours when your date is formatted in sqflite flutter

Tags: flutter, sqlite, sqflite

Hi i have created a sets table in sqflite and you will see in my commented out code I was returning all of the sets in the entire table, but now I want to only return the sets from the last 24hours but I have formatted my date to be dd=MM=yyy.

Here is my create Items Function:

```
//method to create an item to insert into the database table
  static Future<int> createItem(
    String exercise_name,
    String? total_weight,
    String? total_reps,
  ) async {
    DateTime now = DateTime.now();
    String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(now);
    final db = await SQLHelper.db(); //opening the database
    final data = {
      'exercise_name': exercise_name,
      'total_weight': total_weight,
      'total_reps': total_reps,
      'date': formattedDate,
      'is_favorite': 0
    }; //making map to insert
    final id = await db.insert(
        //inserting that data map
        'sets',
        data, //items is table name and data is the map we made
        conflictAlgorithm: sql
            .ConflictAlgorithm.replace); //best practice to prevent duplicates
    return id;
  }
```

And here is the get all Items function where I want to return all of the records in the last 24 hours:

```
  static Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getItems() async {
    final db = await SQLHelper.db(); //get connection
    //return db.query('sets', orderBy: "id");
    return db.query('sets',
        where: "date = ?", whereArgs: []); //limit 1 means get only 1
  }
```

Comment: Change the format of the dates to `yyyy-MM-dd` and then it is easy to solve your problem by using [SQLite's date functions](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html).

Comment: Is there a way to keep it dd-MM-yyyy because it looks much cleaner when displayed to the user in my app

Comment: You can display the dates in any format that you want, but you should store them in the format `yyyy-MM-dd` because this is the only valid text date format for SQLite.

Comment: I followed your comment and it worked, But how would i now display it as dd-MM-yyyy to the user?

Comment: Use Flutter's methods. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57545452/dart-convert-time-from-dd-mm-yyyy-to-yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Hi I am trying to use Jimmy but I dont understand how i can decalre a variable in my list view builder for example i need to declare var date = sets[index][date] but Dart wont let me declare a variable in listview builder. How would i go about doing this?